# Running ImageMagick from C# with scheduled tasks

Tags: c#, process, command, cmd, imagemagick

I have a program that converts PDF-s to images. While running the program manually, everything works. But whenever I try to run the program as a scheduled task, ImageMagick or cmd (not sure) refuses to start and it jumps the step, causing the program to stop.

I have tried running it under different users (both scheduled task and starting the process as a user with privileges), but nothing seems to work and I am left at not understanding or knowing where to start looking next.

My best guess is that is has something to do with user security, and not being allowed to to run imagemagick from a process/cmd in C#.

Code:

```
string args = string.Format("/k convert -density 200 \"{0}\" -quality 40 \"{1}\\{2}\"", file.FullName, imageFolder, file.Name.Replace("pdf", "png"));
using (Process proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = {
        Arguments = args,
        FileName = @"CMD.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true
    }
}) {
    proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived);
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_ErrorDataReceived);
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit(5000);
    proc.Kill();
}
static void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Program.BaseFolder + "\\log.txt")) {
        sw.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
}
static void p_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Program.BaseFolder + "\\log.txt")) {
        sw.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I for funsies just change `args` to 
`string args = string.Format("/k copy {0} {1}", file.FullName, file.FullName + ".to.txt");`

just to copy a file. It works. Seems like it is `convert` that is a problem.

Comment: It seems that schedule tasks and users do not share the same environmental paths.

So I reinstalled ImageMagick, GhostScript and used absolute pathing in the program. This solved my problems. Reinstalling ImageMagick and GhostScript may not have had an effect, but I did it to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *seems* that schedule tasks and users do not share the same environmental paths.

So I reinstalled ImageMagick, GhostScript and used absolute pathing in the program. This solved my problem. But I do not know exactly as I did all those three things, using absolute pathing *may* have solved it alone.

Also removed the timer in `proc.WaitForExit()` and `proc.Kill()` as the process no longer starts `CMD.exe`

```
string args = string.Format("-density 200 \"{0}\" -quality 40 \"{1}\\{2}\"", file.FullName, imageFolder, file.Name.Replace("pdf", "png"));
using (Process proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = {
        Arguments = args,
        FileName = @"c:\imagemagick\convert",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true
    }
}) {
    proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived);
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_ErrorDataReceived);
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running cmd.exe as your filename. You don't seem to be specifiying the actual executable that you want to run anywhere. I would suggest attempt to replace:

```
FileName = @"CMD.exe"
```

With

```
FileName = @"<the executable you want to run>"
```

Comment: That is correct. It is running `CMD.exe`, which is running `convert` in `args`. `convert` is global and can be reached from any directory. Thanks.